# Can I apply for new visitor's visa while current one is still valid?

Tags: visas, canada, applications

I have a Canadian Visitor's Visa that expires in June. I want to travel to Canada in July or August. Can I apply for a new visitor's visa while the current one is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can apply for a new visa, as the validity dates do not overlap.

You should check your passport validity before applying. Canada no longer issues visas that expire after the passport expiration date. You may need to renew your passport first.